# How do I sort colour stacks by a specific field in Vegalite in this example?

Tags: sorting, vega-lite

I'm trying to see how to sort the a bar chart where the color channel is used to encode some information, and in this chart linked below, and well… I'm stumped.

I'm trying to sort the stacked colors by 'yield', so items with the largest yield are at the bottom, but keep the grouping based on 'site' here.

Is this possible with vegalite?

Here's what I would assume would handle the sorting, based on I read [in the documentation on sorting](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html), but I'm not having much luck.

```
"encoding": {
  "color": {
    "type": "nominal",
    "field": "site",
    "sort": {
      "field":"yield",
      "op": "count",
      "order": "ascending"
    }
  },
  "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "variety"},
  "y": {"type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"}
```

}

What do I need to do to sort a bar chart in this way?

[Here's the chart in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6baRHIAmALgBakAsADEwDRS0Fq3WkDMLAL6DW4KJQCG1CaRzwJAWwKlIk6QFomATj4FoBABzQ+AVgBGZgEyUGARm0NoiMwDZbfA3oP2zkEWMgFCQAnAGsVMxDIUQhIAng4SmR4dCxQCFi4ABtYYNlIagBPAAdlLEh4WAVkiSzoqBQCLMoVAGdkamV-DKgAD3yi0pVK6vk69khG5pVcEMIivxiMyEKBkrKoAEcAVwl4ag6pZFxlCYlUVGCCVCkNyFbthXrJwmnywteWwTFuqAASVrQThBFQ8ajFVoYAD0UJONwAdKgOrRtmZ4chYFDAcCJLDrhJ1FkOgRYZZ4S54Ux4QArVoIaIBNQSVoEaitWRiWJMzQ6PSGYzmKw2exaRzONweLw+UgAbU5GXSPWW7U6KgAqvBjgRgirCmAAGIhJ5LJVQWbBearcoAWT2QO2FpkJqVKwIUSwth0tmdPRWn1IlgA7PKIL8eorTfdiSoAOrMvROkPLc2WlS2hIox0M02xQpuvIer0+5YfJotLAMAzwgwuWvB01hhVJ2Iqu7W3IW9nF2Ip1lWqDp+1Z7tQPPusCevje5uj-1YIPwhh8ZcMJONiARl2tlQAYWCsFgoVa1HpI7wcz7abtmeQiZzo-zpEn0-vfrL-C08J0y74a+Lm99bdygAcWCPZKDAAAlCRiioLsZ3PC1Lxta8HVvbMc1dcdnzPUs3jAPgyS0WsXHrJV12wBCgKgAARbYsm2OgMMjXsFhQjM0LvTCxwLCciwQvDyzASwq2Ius-yTADlWjcoNS1HUOj1Q1gmNBDWP7SBgKyCQzH3eBmJdHin3419BMYPhKRIlwJNNHBqMgOMWWgJ0zQvNioC0nS9OeIzCynCYzKwEwTHhSwKLsmSBw7ZAu1cpD3M07TdNPB9sKLWd33nKtAxIwNwqoyLID3A8jxPfSz3UlRPOS8qBMfPyX24ucCKrdwfxspUpJbQrQPAqCYLggzfUqkCku83D6r4-yBOayxPza5cOvDKNVXKOiGKYiYRo8saUqw3icIy-C5vJXL8tfey5JOBSigNI0huTNyNIAZVmeA6WkB7c0mnCZsygiQoW38G3-ArVqgRyEy+uLU3KV69g+rjI18qbGuR5qGEDeEf0WkHJLBttovg19tsgeH3tgT6JrS6bTNmkKcvEvHbIJ3d90PY9TzUp6VHJxHof24zaaa-7mEXXKlqbC6erA+AIOg2DKGJzDSb5ymkcMn6TJF47PyssienCla7nWxj6C2nm4be-mAq1-yjqEywGfOzDLs1a7dTulSBdJgA1JoTl4amDu19H-r4T8tEljdjdjeNnOeP2A9ZHy7e9B3SBMKlLBxo37PbYJO0Ty2oH9rJA9Tmn07fY6KSBl3I3s4qObKn2S8gMuK+DoW0cMjHbGxnHo8o6Xwc02X5YGpW2-ijTO5T7uGtw2aLKYIfmc62O1vos3i9nlR56D1KQ-tmvHYpPgG63Qqru1T3lNUkn24AFSuMxkAFlHfrp8OKRMKzh4RTHpDBOFt97lFfgQd+lcT7V0CmAFwFkDA-jzoVAuRcwGwygJA6Btsq4BQxhZRmpEr6AUKs3UqXMn7gOwW-D+i9UbL1FhSb8uNyKg1HncXqct+qK2VixF+dDP5pyYbreExCDYZFQWPU2m0YbIVoVA+hx8e4EPDhZVhl8OGuxvu7O+ikvaPxVu3AAcrAeEYAGAmEDMI-Bf18JLlChLDey17IgJcohLBkAzEWKsTYvBsC1H4RMK1aRhNC4xT3l4nxljrEwNURnLK4jSHSTHhQzmtVqHRPMbE-xdU7E-wcSFfWgDWYgQnrwwaFVTE5L8bYwJ9ihKEXhLYZx7DJJb1ojvORniFHeNqXEgJCSz78Asi4FJ3Ux63xukpe61SaH9N8S4Sw9TVGNP4BSayLiFSdIcvHDxpMYkMGWfEpeiSEEMzrGEtMRMol9KOScoZZyRlYAENjM62jG7kPZpQzJxiFkPJWQw7+OshKVnhP-EipTOFVQqQrKp3MAW1MefkhphTHYMC-D+Vc2yY72VkebeRCVAWnMYeckSLSJlQDdvJe+czEVeIAApumoNpOWqyl7rNeWSCR0KdHAP2TPJlLK2UtGBaHPuosqyQtrHyr5Y90GRPmcKqQoqOWMK5cJT8NYmbtNsrs9JrdMF9OZaq8CpLDovMsQPcZnzr5j24ZPPhQqTUivNeK4WYd8J8ExZI0M-5dkEruQlU1rL3UqOefAwiVLdnTLpd7ZV9zamBhMOqkFXqMWnV1YbANbjBXGuJcm1NTyyVWuOeIj5HT863ILRpI5KaLXpStZYMktqq3fJKhk4Ndai2NtPvAhgmLbAxvso6yp09E2Ft8Q2j1vdfTwM9OIwBgbumEt6VOyxM6I2lqjavKyI7dG0oMQ-F1CUYwxTgO9ZIYAYkeDTRK+dzUI7Yzlfau47jT0aXPYCBA7R4A3pyXe2doihIhOrK+shCqa0Mr6d+y9f6AMWKA6itZ6KAyfmOdmqRdrIN3ENVQ-5Xi4O-uvbegw97PWSocdqtpOb8YwvKX1eFE6YNnovSR-9ZGKNzpLE+zFmHSIQdSSbVdn7YzsavZxwD5HgOaqnOSITky7hxuPfSrJfTBw3g1vOu2lgQMBhYYp6lhUP2To0ppziFG9NyYsgJv1YAD1QYifwl0pMLPDhQ35azaHXmYr4AA3FI9+V4Z+V2szV4OIedMrp-T3Kvy0ew-R4LsKmNTxc8Ndu7n0Ieu86CgMZIgZGZXRtc2rHzOoSi9xGLmqW0QoS-6pL8rlN6JmYYsTo0vIEeRtVnzBEKQGGXXmpyBz27VXGtuycenzl8CxoGXOua0E1qJRpMbe0v46Cm1a0wLT5uNbfWzTtRqytVV2n87rNNcsZoMy0+rDmcPCZSzw5j6XHoLNW2dzWF3YsTn4+vPVm98WidrSdzr5UJsbaCY7EKOqSH3aU+qFr8ajECIWWrKmnmpqXao47LGS4VyDZM-m5bvNrbqz7ZtqN0rHPhIwcdq2CMyc5e+9tte7VAtdWM2k0LR31MJTR9pksPW8vzipIgtn-3wxlI8nCtL7WoD86s991p5I-t0ZZgxrpJW5dk1J+j6LX2atkhzuLtXnUpeQBU7dE94XyiH0VzV-rBOBXDe7QfZOR9BZech-wXH1ybRLfXXPd35PvevKrMglBcPOchcO111z7c7dM7k2SJgAWJdS2S4xp7subel2D0n3rzTjdsNN64wqQbge2-z+DwiofhJkjs9ThHR6rdqcI30nB9CMeTe+ydVPWGGv6qG1DSvijcE14pxjT8xe-dRWc67iBQiS09-OeWsXy4m-lHwx9jLCzO-2963YasqvEvq8z9L1Lzrc+QH3wX4XwlRcn8HwD8vQPieL6USH6bovN9QEt7MhNOnKAI5QZbvCHB3RcbFJ3d9InQPFQEA-xCfOvBgI3WfSARVWKOA8oBAr-MtCyEwbFX-IqbnOPXfbJXxUA-XE+LHR9cOPzJ-O7PbXDR7J1BFXnHtCgvJKgoWGg3jf6RdOzaAlQCvd-YAgZRAz3THOvWrPKKPWNRHVTQA9g+A5FIFMA2vGrEKGVezNA0zUQxZSxR5JA1fX1NAjAhfMQpZIFYwstWQpgh7LfEgnfV7cgwwtQ7gr3OTKkAgk3U-M3DXceS-Ng9vDdY5dwqrA3XrRdKOdnYrXeUfAwsI3A+BWrEwIg--Nra-UNNVO-K7JJfvQTdnc3UzIAyAbI91dQ3g3MJ9CkVnEvPwsvJzDBfQ8o9lZfCHVfCyMKOQpuJw7XVosVSo3vEKYvYGdPDcc3MdZ7fot1NooYiA3lIogIivUogYg-e-eTfzAfRgs-JrZvD2RQ5HePJFadYteYwvJgIQ8oPQrAywzdYtGwgdAeSwStIfRbefBI+tB4yQlfMtTFUYog7fbXL49YvIgiArBgogqYnPUokE3I7HJ8EYyEhbGRN-W4xIrdH4jo5tLGLY2Hew+HWSBQ1vJQkIr9CTBDLjeE2g71AbJY8-PZF3a-YjSTRDFqUEhEoKVqW7Ig8w5kik0jaTDkmksFLGVpbYwEvo-kn9Vkqk84jYkKGI8YoLPYrPVgljZQ64gUqTJDGTeUsEywUXHkno1-LXaU+DQU3U4UvgsRHGMYw2eUAAXR+BAEECAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `order` channel as described at https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/stack.html#order

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "site"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
    "order": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]